# error in adding listview in alertdialog in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

i am creating alert Dialog with listview in monoandroid xamarin in visual studio.I have below code, here on click of button app crashes,while building its not showing any error but it crashes.

MainActivity.cs

```
namespace DialogSamples
{
    [Activity(Label = "DialogSamples", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
         List<string> _lstDataItem;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it


            btnNormalDialog = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton1);
            btnNormalDialog.Click += methodInvokeAlertDialogWithListView;


        }


        void methodInvokeAlertDialogWithListView(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dlgAlert = (new AlertDialog.Builder(this)).Create();
            dlgAlert.SetTitle("List View Alert Dialog");
            var listView = new ListView(this);
             listView.Adapter = new AlertListViewAdapter(this,
                     (_lstDataItem==null) ? new List<string>() : _lstDataItem);
            listView.ItemClick += listViewItemClick;
            dlgAlert.SetView(listView);
            dlgAlert.SetButton("OK", handllerNotingButton);
            dlgAlert.Show();
        }

        void listViewItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "you clicked on " + _lstDataItem[e.Position], ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
}}
```

AlertListViewAdapter.cs

```
namespace DialogSamples
{
    internal class AlertListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
    {
         MainActivity _context;
         List<string> _lstDataItem;

        public AlertListViewAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<string> lstDataItem)
        {
            this._context = mainActivity;
            this._lstDataItem = lstDataItem;
            _lstDataItem.Add("Person 1");
            _lstDataItem.Add("Person 2");
            _lstDataItem.Add("Person 3");
            _lstDataItem.Add("Person 4");

        }


        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);

            (convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1))
                .SetText(this[position], TextView.BufferType.Normal);

            return convertView;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {

                return _lstDataItem.Count;
            }
        }


        public override string this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return _lstDataItem[index];
            }
        }
}
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where have you initialized `List<string> _lstDataItem` ? I think it is passing null over here

Comment: @kyle  In  AlertListViewAdapter.cs file

Comment: No thats where you are receiving the value. `listView.Adapter = new AlertListViewAdapter(this, _lstDataItem);` in this line the value you are passing is null.

Comment: @kyle can you please explain me were should i initialize data ,i am very new to c#.With some code will be very helpfull

Comment: goto output window any error?

Comment: @Jagadeesh Govindaraj In my code i am not able to get the index of listview row on click.app crashes if i do so

Answer (score 0):

In your `methodInvokeAlertDialogWithListView` replace

```
 listView.Adapter = new AlertListViewAdapter(this, _lstDataItem);
```

with

```
 listView.Adapter = new AlertListViewAdapter(this,
                         (_lstDataItem==null) ? new List<string>() : _lstDataItem);
```

Comment: it works ,but what is the correct way to add_lstDataItem.Add("Person 1"); in my app

Comment: @dafodil  now i am able to get listview but on click of list my app is crashing

Comment: should i use get and set class to retrieve listview row position on click.Here app is crashing on click of listview row.Sorry to ask this simple question but i am very new to c#.and folowing this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/685970/MonoAndroid-Using-AlertDialog